# Xamarin build results in “The application has not been built”

Tags: xamarin.forms

Then when I deploy the app in Debug configuration, I will get a popup saying that "The Application has not been built."

Comment: There will likely be an output to the error window in visual studio (assuming you are using visual studio on windows?) this would give you and us a better idea of what the problem could be. As it stands your question is so broad, and with no code or stack trace it's impossible for any of us to help you.

Comment: FWIW, (for anyone like me hitting this problem in 2023) the fix for me was exit VS, delete all the content in both `obj` and `bin` folders, restart the Mac.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem with a .NET 8 MAUI App, running on a M1 mac.

It went away after I changed the "RuntimeIdentifiers" in the *.csproj file to "maccatalyst-arm64"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check you solution Configuration Manager. Make sure your target is set to build
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had accidentally chosen a Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile for the Debug configuration (I intended to do this a few days prior for Release config)

Check your settings are similar to mine:

[image: Provisioning Profiles]